# how to omit a file if it does not exist - openpyxl, os

Tags: python, openpyxl, shutil

i am using openpyxl to help bulk copy particular filoes from a list within Excel. currently the process being followed is:
Search a worksheet for a particular filename prefix
if file name is found in list, and begins with specific prefix, copy from folder:

```
#Import required modules
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import os
import shutil
# Enter source folder

source = ("C:\\Users\\alec.litchfield\\Desktop\\Resized images\\")
# Enter destiantion folder - this must exist.
destination = ("C:\\Users\\alec.litchfield\\Desktop\\Stripped Blackpool Photos\\")
# Enter the name of your Excel Workbook (including the extension):
workBookName = ("C:\\Users\\alec.litchfield\\Desktop\\2017.11.22 Point Data - Master.xlsx") #input("Enter the name of your Excel Workbook (including the extension): ")
workSheetName = ("Point data") #input("Enter the name of the work sheet to read from: ")
RowRange = int(input ("add total number of rows to check: "))
workBook = load_workbook(filename = workBookName, read_only=True,data_only=True)
workSheet = workBook[workSheetName]
#filepath = ("C:\\Users\\alec.litchfield\\Desktop\\My Personal Folder\\Python lessons\\Photo copy paste\\")
for x in range(2, RowRange):
    file = str (workSheet["j" + str(x)].value)
          if file.startswith(('P1010','P1020', 'P1070','P1060','P1050' 'P1040' 'P1020' )):
        shutil.copyfile (source + file, destination + file)
```

The problem i am getting, is that if the file does not exist, then the process stops. this only takes one to cause the stoppage, and is problematic when dealing with the numebr of files that we are copying (4000)

is there a simple addition to the code in order to tell it 'if the file doesnt exist, ignore and move on'

Many thanks in advance!

Alec

Comment: `os.path.isfile(workBookName)`

Answer (score 0):

Check out the python exceptions functions (try, except, finally)

For example:

```
try:
    #do stuff with the file here
except FileNotFoundError:
    #do nothing if the file is not found
    pass
```